# Asset Managers with minify & grouping options for standard HTML sites

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, css, cakephp

I mainly work with the CakePHP framework, with the use of the very cool added plugin that minify and groups selected assets into one whole file, therefore making only one HTTP request for the whole site.

I am now working with designers, who although want very cool dynamically built sites, do not like losing control over building the CSS / design within Dreamweaver. Although just to add, I will add I think I possible am better with CSS - I am now normally using SCSS - than they are :).

So they want to still build in standard CSS and html, I can add things in like backbone to give me router / path management. - Although I have not used it before, so some learning to do there :).

But want I really want to know is, if there are any ways I can group / minify assets just using a PHP plugin? Or a Node.JS plugin which would just output the files I need (it will be a standard web hosting, so no Node.JS support). I think a PHP plugin would be best?

Any ideas?

Or should I look at building one myself?

Thanks Glenn.

Comment: For CakePHP: https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/). It's a powerful tool that can compile/minify javascript, scss, css, r.js and many more.

It's nodejs based, so you can simply install it with `npm` and configure the output of your files in a `/public` folder which you can upload to your hosting service.

The only need of node.js is on your development environment.

It supports from the box plugins like `watch` which can recompile / minify at edit mode and there are tons of plugins that can help you with such tasks.

It's pretty much a standart for NodeJS projects.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at Grunt but I did not know it supported SCSS or CSS. Does it support SCSS without the Compass/SASS ruby gem? But may thanks, Glenn.

Comment: Yes it supports compass, but you will need the ruby gems for compilation. Anyhow you can easily install them only on your dev. machine and don't need them on production. :) https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-compass